# jQuery removing too much html

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a generated `table` that has too many `<td>` elements. I call

```
$('#Container td[class!="SlideInfo"]').remove();
```

to remove all of the unwanted `<td>` elements that does not have the class name `SlideInfo` on it. Problem is that I have a inner table (child) that gets removed as well. How can I tell jQuery to only remove the siblings of the `<td>`s not the inner one as well.

Starts off

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="SlideInfo">
    <table>
        <td class="SlideInfo">
            This gets removed, I know the html is wrong on this but this is an example.
        </td>
    </table>
</td>

<td class="SlideInfo">
    <table>
        <td class="SlideInfo">
            This gets removed, I know the html is wrong on this but this is an example.
        </td>
    </table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I call `$('#Container td[class!="SlideInfo"]').remove();` and it removes those unwanted `td`'s but it also removes the children `td`'s of the ones I do want.

Comment: How would you differentiate between the ones you want removed and the ones you don't want removed?

Comment: I would not rely on jQuery to fix bad HTML.  Why not fix the root problem instead?

Comment: @pb they have a class on the ones I want.

Comment: @sparky. I have tried for hours but no luck. I have no clue why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the child selector '>' which will only look for the matching elements among the immediate children of the container. Try this

```
$('#Container > td[class!="SlideInfo"]').remove();
```

Comment: Even though i should look at the root cause this will work for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct selector is this

```
$('#Container>td[class!="SlideInfo"]').remove();
```

It selects only child elements of #Container.  However, if #Container is in fact a `table` element and not a `tr`, you may need something like this:

```
$('#Container>tr>td[class!="SlideInfo"]').remove();
```

or this

```
$('#Container>tbody>tr>td[class!="SlideInfo"]').remove();
```

Comment: I voted Joseph's answer up.  It takes into account both to "tr" tag and possible "tbody" tags

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "child selector".

```
$('#Container > tr > td[class!="SlideInfo"]').remove();
```

Notice the greater than sign in the selector.  Also note, that you should use the "tr" tag before the greater-than sign.

Otherwise, the selector is claiming that there should be a "td" tag as a direct child of a whatever is marked as "#Container".  If "#container" is the id on the "table" tag, I'm not sure if the selector will work correct.

The ">" says to "select only the children of parent".   Thus, grandchildren should not be selected.  This assumes that your table has an id of "Container".